# How Can i detect changes in child

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an empty array on begin. After that i push objects to that array.

This array is in parent component and it is passed by [input] to the child
the problem is when i add a object to arry the child doesnt detect any changes.

I use ngOnChanges and when i extend array there is no logs with changes :(

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log('my changes', changes);
   }
```

So i dont know how it realy works how i can call any action when childs knows the parent data changed

Comment: Changing the content of an array or object is not covered by angulars change detection. You can check for changes yourself like for example the `ngClass` directive does https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/45cc4441540beba041762c7b0435e839df84e6a4/modules/%40angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.ts#L79, or you can use an observable in a shared service where the child subscribes to, to get notified about changes.

Comment: Plunker would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to log the "changes" per say but you can still call an action inside *ngOnChanges*

If your @Input gets updated data *ngOnChanges* will fire and you can call a function in there. For eg.

```
@Input() listings: List; //assume this is array of list

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

  if(this.listings)
    this.onClick(this.listings[0]); //on changes, call Onclick on 1st list

}

onClick(list){
//do something with list
}
```

Answer (score 1):

detecting the changes that occur on child component and pass it to parent component using @output and EventEmitter concept

```
@Output() userName : EventEmitter<string>= new EventEmitter<string>();
```

and in parent component template call the above used variable

```
 <child-component (userName)='OnDataChange($event)'></child-component>
```

[Full Reference](https://www.fourthbottle.com/2018/08/output-with-eventemitter-in-angular.html)